# Magento 2.3: cache issue - changes are uploading with long delay

Tags: magento2.3, cache, upgrade, upload, production-mode

We have got installed Magento 2.3 on our production server.

Whenever we do changes to css file or other Magento files it takes ages to reflect the page on the live website. The brutal method to get the changes to be visible on the live page is to deploy static content, sometimes it helped to clear the static content, but sometimes the same doing didn't help, we have tried also to clear the preprocessed cache folder and all cache in the var folder, but it keeps regenerating with the old cache.

We are now out of ideas on why it is behaving in this way.

We have got the stagging server where we do the same changes and they are applied straight away.

Anyone would know why?

We don't have CDN and the server was checked. Our server is on Linux.

Comment: remove generated/code & generated/metadata folder in your root directory after deploying new changes.

Comment: It might your server issue. Ask your hosting provider any additional cache implement on server...